# Fill in gaps with consecutive numbers and also copy preceed values

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I have two files, one contains:

```
2035.00 0 0 70 70 90 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100

2038.00 0 0 70 70 70 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100

2040.00 0 0 60 60 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
```

and the other contains:

```
2035.00 0 0 70 70 90 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100

2036.00 0 0 70 70 90 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100

2037.00 0 0 70 70 90 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100

2038.00 0 0 70 70 70 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100

2039.00 0 0 70 70 70 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100

2040.00 0 0 60 60 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
```

and I would like to fill in gaps with consecutive numbers from the first values of the first column and also fill the others fields following values from the proceed fields as I you see in the second file

Thanks in advance

Ana

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be sure to review [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for tips on how to ask better questions; what have you tried so far?  What got you closer to your desired solution and what didn't?

Comment: what kind of interpolation are you looking for? and are you using numpy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
awk -f a.awk file
```

where `a.awk` is:

```
NF>0{
    a[($1+0)]=$0
}
END {
    for (i=2035; i<=2040; i+=0.5) {
       if (i in a) {
           b=a[i]; q=i; c=b
        } else {
            b=c
            z=sprintf("%.2f ",i)
            sub(/^[^[:blank:]]* /,z,b)
        }
        print b
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2035.00 0 0 70 70 90 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
2035.50 0 0 70 70 90 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
2036.00 0 0 70 70 90 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
2036.50 0 0 70 70 90 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
2037.00 0 0 70 70 90 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
2037.50 0 0 70 70 90 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
2038.00 0 0 70 70 70 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
2038.50 0 0 70 70 70 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
2039.00 0 0 70 70 70 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
2039.50 0 0 70 70 70 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
2040.00 0 0 60 60 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
```

Answer (score 2):

Using awk

```
awk 'NR==1{print $0 RS;a=$1;$1="";b=$0;next}
     NF!=0{if (a+1!=$i)for (i=a+1;i<$1;i++) printf "%.2f%s\n\n", i,b;print $0 RS;a=$1;$1="";b=$0;}' file
```